# Get Dynamic States from the JSON using the Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Here is my JSON where menulist is my main menu where list are the states

```
[{
"menulist":
[{"list":"veg",
"id":1
},
{"list":"nonveg",
"id":2
},
{"list":"offer",
"id":3
 },
 {"list":"combo",
"id":4
 },
 {"list":"rice",
 "id":5
 }]
 }]
```

I want to access those list using the $resource. I Have created all Factories, Services,Controllers. Here is Factory

```
   factmodule.factory("BreakfastFactory",function($resource){

var breakmenuinfo;
var breakmenuResource=$resource("json/breakfast/breakmenu.json/:menulist",  {"menulist":"@menulist"},{update:{method:"get"}});
return{
    getbreakmenu: function(){
    breakmenuinfo=breakmenuResource.query();
        return breakmenuinfo;

}}
```

})

Here is Service

```
 servctrl.service("Breakfastservice",function(BreakfastFactory,OrderFactory,WishFactory){

this.getAllBreakMenu=function(){
    return BreakfastFactory.getbreakmenu();
}
```

})

Here is controller

```
mainCtrl.controller("MainController",function($scope,Breakfastservice){
 $scope.mainmenulist=Breakfastservice.getAllBreakMenu();
});
```

Here is my Html code, where i want to access

```
 <ul ng-repeat="list1 in mainmenulist">
       <li><a href="" ui-sref="menu.break.({id:list1.list})">{{list1.list}}</a></li></ul>
```

Strictly $resource only.
Help me out of this.Thank U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the dynamic states from JSON. Its not possible, as the json is the static. Here we can do only the get operations, as per my knowledge. So no dynamic states could be loaded